# any downsides to installing eslint globally?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm working on a React project that does not yet use a linter as part of the project. I want to avoid checking in eslint as part of the project so I'm considering installing eslint globally on my laptop.  Here's the npm page for eslint:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react

Per the documentation on this page:

"Install ESLint either locally or globally. (Note that locally, per project, is strongly preferred)"

Are there any downsides to installing eslint globally?  As a matter of practice, a local project install is better practice.  But I wasn't sure if there were any practical downsides that I should be aware of for installing ESLint globally.

Comment: You can install it globally, but versioning and compatibility between different projects can become a problem pretty soon if you work on several different projects. Choose local installations, because each project has its own requirements that may differ from other projects. This is even more true if you are working in a team.

Comment: Another good reason to install it locally is to have it available for the CI, and then have a linting step that validates code before it gets merged.

Comment: yes i totally agree with the points in both of your comments.  the organization that i'm working for is new to react and the modern spa ecosystem so i need to take baby steps.  the first step will be for me to go through a few cycles for eslint in my own development environment before introducing it to the broader team